# How to setup Github SSH key on second computer

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I've got a Github account setup on one computer. I would like to also access my Github account on a second machine using the same SSH key I used for the first computer. How do I import the SSH private key into the new computers user profile?

```
cp ~/other_comp_github_key ~/.ssh/github
```

The above command did not do the job in the git bash console on Windows.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It'd be best to create a new private key if github allows you to have several associated with your account. (Sharing private keys among machines is very much like sharing passwords on multiple accounts.) But not all services allow multiple keys, so...

You don't specify that you copied the private portion of the key; make sure you copy the private portion.

You don't specify that you configured the `~/.ssh/config` block to use the `~/.ssh/github` key for the `github.com` host. Make sure you add a new block to your `~/.ssh/config` file just like block on the machine you stole the key from.

```
host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
```

(I don't know that the host is `github.com` -- if you use a different hostname, then use that.)

Comment: The better thing seems to be to create a new key. I will create a new key since Github also supports many keys. Accepting your answer because it also shows me how to force the key moving if I really need that. Good for SEO.

Answer (score 34):

Argh! No!

### **Do. Not. Share. Private. Keys.**

Make a *new* keypair on the second computer.

Comment: For the sake of learning: Why is it a bad idea to share private keys?

Comment: @ILiketoCode to quote the accepted answer: _"Sharing private keys among machines is very much like sharing passwords on multiple accounts."_

Comment: @MattBall Which is completely ok in common use. :)

Comment: Sharing private keys between your own computers is more akin to logging into your bank with the same password from multiple computers rather than using the same password with different accounts.  When you use the same password with two different sites, you are giving those sites information about how to log into the each other's sites.   That isn't the case with copying your private keys between your own computers.

Answer (score 2):

The copying of the private key will work, iff the *permissions* to the ssh files copied are correct, i.e. readable for the user who uses the keys, something like 555 will do. Also, since github allows multiple ssh keys to be used with same account, you can create a new keypair and add it to your account.

Comment: Note that `555` will also set the executable bit on the key file, which isn't necessary. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, simply create a new SSH Key in the other computer since its not advisable sharing the same SSH Keys across different computers.

Follow these sets of instructions on Github,I found them pretty much direct and easy to follow.

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent