# How to use same github SSH key from linux to windows

Tags: linux, windows, github

I have connected my GitHub account with Linux, but now I want to connect my GitHub with the same SSH key on windows. Could it be possible? and how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is probably *possible* to re-use your same key - but it is recommended to create a new keypair on the new machine.

You can then add the other public key to your GitHub account as well.

See also: [How to setup Github SSH key on second computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753014/how-to-setup-github-ssh-key-on-second-computer)